Meaning of this text ("Um es erst mal klarzustellen: Man sollte Eigenkapital haben.")
This is a text from a B1 Modelltest. It's someone's opinion on the topic "Wohneigentum".

Um es erst mal klarzustellen: Man sollte Eigenkapital haben. Und da ich keins habe, sage ich nein dazu. Denn bei einer Eigentumswohnung ist es so, dass die Besitzer, wenn Arbeiten am oder im Haus zu machen sind, dafür die Kosten tragen müssen. Ok, Treppenhaus streichen geht da ja noch, aber wenn zum Beispiel das Haus ein neues Dach braucht, kann das ganz schön teuer werden.
Elke, 40, Rosenheim

I can tell that the person is against homeownership, but I really don't understand the point of the first sentence and how it's logically connected to the rest of the text.
I would translate the beginning of the text like this:
To make it clear first: You should have your own capital. And since I don't have any, I say no to that.
The first and second sentence sound like complete opposites, while at the same time both being presented as her opinion.
Could someone please explain what these sentences are supposed to mean?

"To make it clear first" is more or less correct, but perhaps unidiomatic in English. Try "first off", "up front", etc..


Und da ich keins habe, sage ich nein dazu

This dazu refers back to Wohneigentum, not Eigenkapital.
You can't tell this from the grammar, only from context.

The text in general talks about the importance of own capital when purchasing your own home. The writer explains they don't have own capital and thus do not want to be a homeowner, as they could not pay for maintenance of the property.
This is what the first two sentences want to get across as well: As you wrote, the first sentence says "To make it clear first: You should have your own capital." and the second says "And since I don't have any, I say no to that." The 'any' refers to own capital here, while 'that' refers to homeownership. Thus, what the second sentence is saying is that because the writer does not have own capital, they are against purchasing a home for themself. They don't appear to be against homeownership in general.
